# Форма фразеологизма

Tags: фразеология

"Милости просим" звучит как обращение от множественного числа. Правильно ли будет одному человеку сказать "милости прошу", или фразеологизм так и должен звучать, неизменным?

Answer (score 3):

**Милости просим (прошу)**
*Устар.* В речевом этикете: выражение вежливого приглашения прийти, приехать в гости или войти, чтобы принять участие в беседе, в обсуждении чего-либо.
[**Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка**](http://phraseology.academic.ru/10047/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%29)

*—  Милости прошу, милости прошу, — оживился старик. — Кого Бог-от послал?

...

 —  Милости просим, милости просим, — ласково суетился Митяич. — Кипяточку-от, кипяточку не желаете ль?*
[**Были и небыли. Книга 1. Господа волонтеры**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=WT6lAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT194&lpg=PT194&dq=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83&source=bl&ots=TPs2qU7oWa&sig=FAADOgVy3uL19tCoJrnsG1x0Aho&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEj4q6jLnVAhVKKVAKHZXUD0E4FBDoAQhBMAU#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83&f=false)

*У нас хотя и не Париж, но милости просим к нашему шалашу.

Милости прошу к нашему шалашу: я пирогов покрошу и откушать попрошу.

Милости просим, люд честной, к нашим молодым на сыр-каравай!

Милости прошу, к нашему грошу, со своим пятаком!*

**Милости прошу**(синонимы):
***милости просим***, прошу тебя, покорно, пожалуйста, прошу вас, покорнейше прошу, прошу покорнейше, добро пожаловать, прошу.
(Словарь синонимов русского языка)

Получается, что это один и тот же фразеологизм(с различием в числе).

Answer (score 1):

В Фразеологическом словаре русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ. А. И. Фёдоров. 2008, закреплены обе формы.

Милости просим (прошу)
    Устар. В речевом этикете: выражение вежливого приглашения прийти, приехать в гости или войти, чтобы принять участие в беседе, в обсуждении чего-либо. — Здравствуй, Иван Лукич, здравствуй, друг! — пожимал ему руку Батманов. — В гости к тебе пожаловали. — Милости просим, — опять поклонился Карпов (В. Ажаев. Далеко от Москвы)